# Exporting SqlRowSet to a file

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, design-patterns, refactoring

I want to export the results of an SQL query, fired through JDBC, to a file; and then import that result, at some point later.

I'm currently doing it by querying the database through a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` of `Spring` which returns a `SqlRowSet` that I can iterate. In each iteration, I extract desired fields and dump the result into a `CSV` file, using `PrintWriter`.

```
final SqlRowSet rs = namedJdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sql,params);
while (rs.next()) {
```

The problem is that when I read back the file, they are all `String`s and I need to cast them to their proper types, e.g `Integer`, `String`, `Date` etc.

```
while (line != null) {
    String[] csvLine = line.split(";");

    Object[] params = new Object[14]; 
    params[0] = csvLine[0];
    params[1] = csvLine[1];
    params[2] = Integer.parseInt(csvLine[2]);
    params[3] = csvLine[3];
    params[4] = csvLine[4];
    params[5] = Integer.parseInt(csvLine[5]);
    params[6] = Integer.parseInt(csvLine[6]);
    params[7] = Long.parseLong(csvLine[7]);
    params[8] = formatter.parse(csvLine[8]);
    params[9] = Integer.parseInt(csvLine[9]);
    params[10] = Double.parseDouble(csvLine[10]);
    params[11] = Double.parseDouble(csvLine[11]);
    params[12] = Double.parseDouble(csvLine[12]);
    params[13] = Double.parseDouble(csvLine[13]);

    batchParams.add(params);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

**Is there a better way to export this `SqlRowSet` to a file in order to facilitate the import process later on; some way to store the schema for an easier insertion into the DB?**

Answer (score 0):

If parsing is your concern, one way of handling this is,

1. Create a parser `Factory` interface, say `ParserFactory`
2. Create a parse interface, say `MyParser`
3. Have `MyParser` implemented using Factory Method `Pattern`, i.e. `IntegerParser implements MyParser` etc.
4. Have your factory class names as a header in your CSV

This way your calling code would look like,

```
List<String> headerRow = reader.readLine().split(";"); // Get the 1st row here 
Map<String, MyParser> parsers = new HashMap<>();    
for(int i = 0; i < headerRow.length(); i++) {
    if(!parser.containsKey(headerRow[i]))
        parsers.put(headerRow[i], ParserFactory.get(headerRow[i]));
}

line = reader.readLine();
while (line != null) { // From 2nd row onwards
    String[] row = line.split(";");

    Object[] params = new Object[row.length()]; 
    for(int i = 0; i<row.length(); i++) {
        params[i] = parser.get(headerRow[i]).parse(row[i]);
    }

    batchParams.add(params);
    line = reader.readLine();
}
```

You might like to extract out the creation of parser map, into it's own method. Or let your `ParserFactory` take `headerRow` as parameter, and return respective parsers as a result. Something like,

```
List<String> headerRow = reader.readLine().split(";"); // Get the 1st row here 
Map<String, MyParser> parsers = ParserFactory.getParsers(headerRow);
```